# how to play notification sound in html5 android app : [phonegap]?

Tags: android, html, notifications, alert, phonegap-build

straight to the point, I have developed a normal web app with html5, js and css3 with scripting language as PHP. I wrapped it up using build.phonegap with a proper config.xml. That application has a code to count the total due on some customers, and it it showing alert if the money due reaches to certain limit. The only point I am lagging into is how to put this alerts with notification sounds (ringtones/alerts).

I have googled it all over but coudn't find anything. Can somebody guide me in proper direction that how it should be implemented in android html5 apps??

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Media plugin?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to write this:

navigator.notification.beep(1);

The only parameter beep() function takes is for the length of your notification sound.

By default it will make the notification sound you hear on common alerts like for an SMS or other updates.